# Another class's method call Lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

When I try to call method of other class from another class it says error message that,

```
Attempt to call field 'LoadShift' (a nil value)
```

Here's my code,
loginpage1.lua

```
local LoadShift = nil;
.
.
function LoadShift()

end
```

loginpage2.lua

```
local loginObj = require("com.classess.loginpage1")
loginObj.LoadShift();
```

What's the problem with my code, Please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make your custom class like this

```
------------Your class LoadShift---------------
    local LoadShift = {}
    .
    .
    function LoadShift:LoadShiftFunc()
        --do somthing
    end
    .
    .
    return LoadShift
-------------------------------------
```

then require it and call that function like

```
---------------------

local LoadShift= require "LoadShift"
LoadShift:LoadShiftFunc()
```

Comment: @Fazil: Check the spelling and capitalization of your LUA class. Is it named as 'LoadShift.lua' ..? Then only the above code will work...

Comment: i did no spell mistake

Comment: @Fazil: RAIS's answer has to work. Refer the following link also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205978/how-to-make-one-display-group-stay-fixed-in-every-scene-in-corona/18213918#18213918